# How do I access other components' variables with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm working with angular and I have a on/off button in my HeaderComponent and i'd like to display data in my AboutComponent according to the value of my button

E.g :

```
<div *ngIf="butttonValue === 'on'">Some text</div>
<div *ngIf="butttonValue === 'off'">Some other text</div>
```

Problem is, I don't know how to access the my variable from my AboutComponent

I've seen some using services while others used the @input decorator, but i'm no sure how to use either of them, I hope some of you can enlight me !

Thanks

Comment: What is the relationship between your components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a service like this:

   @Injectable()
   export class MyService {
     buttonValue: string;
   }
2. Add that service to AppModule list of providers.
3. In both of your components inject public myService: MyService in the constructor.

Now you can refer to it as myService.buttonValue.

Comment: Well, you just solved my problem with 3 lines while i couldn't take what i wanted from the documentation ! 

Thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 1):

To share information between components, you can use either of these 2 approaches -

- Create a shared service
- Use [@Input/@Output](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties) Bindings

@Input() binding let component receive value from its parent component, Whereas @Output() let the child component to send data out to its parent component.

In your case you can use them as follows -

- Create a output binding on button state in *Header Component*. This will transfer the value of button whenever it is modified to *app component*.
- Create a input binding inside *About Component* to receive in the value of button from header component.

Check this [demo application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inter-component-communication?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) which illustrates passing data between components using @Input/@Output binding.

For further readings refer - [Component Interaction - Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

Best to follow the component interaction patterns that [Angular recommends](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding). Check out that guide -- the first section on passing data with input binding is probably what you want. That's the  most typical.

Accessing data on a parent component directly from a child is a bad practice since hard-coding a reference to a particular calling component limits the reusability of the child component.